# Java - Unable to call Abstract class methods that extend a super non-abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class, extends

super class called phone (non-abstract), then 1 abstract class that extends it called "developer1" then last concrete class called "developer2" that extends the abstract "developer1". The problem is that I have been asked to instantiate using Phone(super class) and access everything through the last class. I get no errors but I cannot see nor access any methods of any other class but the super class.

```java
class Phone {
    private String brand;

    public Phone(){
        this.brand="samsung";
    }
    public void show(){
        System.out.println("current phone");
    }
}

abstract class DeveloperOne extends Phone{

    public DeveloperOne() {
        super();
    }

    public void newRingtone(){
        System.out.println("new ringtone developed");
    }

    abstract void phoneTv();
}

class DeveloperTwo extends DeveloperOne {

    @Override
    public void phoneTv() {
        System.out.println("phone tv developed");
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PhoneParent phone = new DeveloperTwo();    //this dynamic binding is required
    }
}
```

Problem is here, I cannot see or access any methods of the developerOne OR DeveloperTwo classes, I can only see and access stuff from Phone (super class). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           PhoneParent phone = new DeveloperTwo();  //this dynamic binding is required
 }
```

There is no class called `PhoneParent`. I presume that is a typo. You should instantiate it as `DeveloperTwo`.

```
DeveloperTwo phone = new DeveloperTwo();
```

Otherwise, all you will see are `Phone` class`s methods.

You can also do this.

```
Phone phone = new DeveloperTwo();
DeveloperTwo devel = (DeveloperTwo) phone; // casting
```

Then use the `devel` instance to access the methods.

Comment: but why is that??? in just inheritance of classes extending others I can access anything from sub to super class using same way. As soon as I put one abstract class in the middle, it doesn't work..... why doesn't it work?

Comment: In any class hierarchy if you instantiate the lowest class in the hierarchy as the top most (parent) class, all you will be able to access are fields and methods of the parent class.  If you did not experience that then you did something differently.  I recommend you provide both examples.  If you instantiate your lower class as `Phone`, all you will be able to access are `Phone's` methods.

Comment: You are right. I tested what you said. I have a question for you which is confusing me even more now knowing this. Why would one even use dynamic binding(polymorphism) Parent phone = new subclass(); when by just instantiating all the classes sub and parent with their own kind to have full access. Also what is the best use for abstract class when you can just have a interface with all abstract methods and use it with normal inheritance... Thanks

Comment: Remember the instance is still an instance of the lower subclass.  So if the sub class overrides any of the parents methods, when you access that method via a parent type it will execute the overridden method.  And instead of using Phone, lets use `Shape`.  You can have `Ovals`, or `Circles` or `Rectangles`,etc.  You might want to store them all in a list so it would be `List<Shape>` and you can access a method common to all, like `getArea()` or `getPerimeter()`.  This is especially true of `Interfaces` which are used to implement a set of methods common to all implementations.

Comment: Hi I have a question with same program but a little different issue, if you can pls let me know. When you have simple inheritance class A with its own constructor and class B extending A and class C extending B. does the B and C really need 2 separate constructors, one to only call super(); and 2nd to also call super plus set their own variables. Thanks